# array of objects modifies as array of arrays of objects after saving in DB

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

Hello guys i have this problem here, i send stringified array of objects to server `[{foo: 'bar', bar: 'foo'}, {foo: 'bar1', bar: 'foo1'}]` and after saving it into DB in this property (after i parse it)

```
ingredients: {
    type: Schema.Types.Array,
    default: [],
    required: true        
 },
```

and query it it turn to `[ [ {foo: 'bar', bar: 'foo'} ], [ {foo: 'bar1', bar: 'foo1'} ] ]`

why does this happen and how can it be fixed? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why it happens, but you could [flatten](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) the array:

```
var arr1 = [1, 2, [3, 4]];
arr1.flat(); 
// [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: i need it to be correct in db, there are many methods to make array flat

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've made a mistake defining the Schema.

Based in your Schema you're storing arrays. So that's why you get an array of arrays back.

Try changing the Schema to store Ingredients and not Arrays.

Hope it helps!

Comment: how can change it?